# SQL Server: Unicode file expected when trying to view an error log

Tags: sql-server

We get this following error trying to view a SQL Server error log file:

> Msg 22004, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Unicode file expected.

And we can't create a new one. Help!

Comment: have you restart the service? is there any file system issue? crash? connection failure? wich sql version?

Comment: ok, time to sleep, take a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182512.aspx  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34334/how-can-i-change-sql-agent-log-file-to-use-unicode-format/34422#34422  and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49364/sql-server-2012-sql-log-the-log-file-is-not-using-unicode-format